# $(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot1 = \frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Here is a question from the book *An Introduction to The Theory of Numbers* by Ivan Niven.

> Suppose that $\mathbb{L}$ contains $2n$ elements, and that $\mathbb{L}$ is partitioned into $n$ disjoint subsets each one containing exactly two elements of $\mathbb{L}$. Show that this can be done in precisely
>   $$(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot1 = \frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$ ways.

**My Question**

I do not understand how did he moved to this expression $(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot1$ since, up to my understanding, choosing $n$ subsets of $2n$ set with $2$ elements each is $\Pi_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2}$. Furthermore, how $$(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot1 = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}??$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you select a pair out of $2n$ (there are $\binom{2n}{2}$ possibilities).

Then you select a pair out of the remaining $2n-2$ (there are $\binom{2n-2}{2}$ possibilities).

Et cetera.

That gives $\binom{2n}2\binom{2n-2}2\cdots\binom42\binom22=\frac{(2n)!}{2!2!\cdots2!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$ possibilities.

But like this every partition has been counted $n!$ times so we must divide by $n!$ to repair that.

This leads to $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$ partitions.

Comment: Many thanks,, This is beautifully explained.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $2$, then by $4$, then by $6$, etc....:

$$1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n}=\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, but can you also elaborate more on the first part of the question,,

Comment: I honestly don't understand what do you mean with "move the expression": he just did what I did without explanation, and I explained I think what he did. There's nothing here related with subsets with two elements out of a set with $\;n\;$ elements, unless you can recognize here some binomial coefficient, which is **not**, as far as I can see, the point here.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that:

$$2^n n! = 2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot 2(n-1) \cdot 2n$$

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate more on the first part of the question,,